# Is there any API available to create instance(VM) on amazon by access token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**Purpose**:
I want to create aws instance(VM) programmatically on user AWS console.

**Findings**:
I found there is aws-sdk available with runInstance method which will create instance but It must require accessKeyId, secretAccessKey of use which is confidentials I guess.

**Question**:
Is there a way by which from my application user will redirect to the amazon authentication page then redirect back with access token and using this access token I can able to create VM?

**Is there any API available to create instance(VM) on amazon by access token?**

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html

Answer (score 0):

Each AWS user is provided with both access key and secret key. You can get those keys under IAM service in your AWS management console. Here is the image of IAM console

[image: IAM console]

The access keys can be viewed all the time, but secret keys are given only at the time of creation. So, both access keys and secret keys can be downloaded as **credentials.csv**.

**Your question:** Is there a way by which from my application user will redirect to the amazon authentication page then redirect back with access token and using this access token I can able to create VM?

There is no authentication like Oauth to receive secret key every time you access AWS. Once you load both the keys into the API everything is done. You can access AWS services through API unless you delete those keys explicitly.

There are lot of AWS sdk-platforms available. They have the browser version, nodeJS, command line, ruby, etc.,

Assuming you are creating EC2 instance from command line, store both access-key and secret key as environment variables in the format:

**AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:** [your access key]

**AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:** [your secret key]

Further creating EC2 instance is [straight forward](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-ec2-launch.html#launching-instances).

Comment: Thanks @Lakshman Diwaakar for your detail explanation. But I am still in hope for the Oauth flow in amazon.
Thanks Again